# gSOAP: wsdl2h option -L changes to much

Tags: c++, soap, gsoap

I am using wsdl2h on two different systems, CentOS 8 and RHEL7. On the latter, only an older version is available which does not support argument "-L". This should not be problem because option "-L" should not change any important part of generated files. However, this is generated in TestStub.h
with newer wsdl2h v2.8.91 and "-L":

```
#define SOAP_NAMESPACE_OF_Test1 "http://system.test.com/datatypes/tehnicalException"
#define SOAP_NAMESPACE_OF_Test2 "http://system.test.com/datatypes/common"
#define SOAP_NAMESPACE_OF_Test3 "http://test.company.com/MyService"
#define SOAP_NAMESPACE_OF_Test4 "http://test.company.com/"
```

And this is what I get from both, older wsdl2h v2.8.16 and newer v2.8.91, without "-L":

```
#define SOAP_NAMESPACE_OF_Test2 "http://system.test.com/datatypes/tehnicalException"
#define SOAP_NAMESPACE_OF_Test3 "http://system.test.com/datatypes/common"
#define SOAP_NAMESPACE_OF_Test1 "http://test.company.com/MyService"
#define SOAP_NAMESPACE_OF_Test4 "http://test.company.com/"
```

They are different! Sorry, I cannot post real files.

EDITED: Probably, the problem originates in the generated Test.h.

```
/******************************************************************************\
 *                                                                            *
 * Forward Declarations                                                       *
 *                                                                            *
\******************************************************************************/

class Test1__TechnicalExceptionInfoType;
```

Compare this with the result without using "-L":

```
/******************************************************************************\
 *                                                                            *
 * Forward Declarations                                                       *
 *                                                                            *
\******************************************************************************/

class Test2__TechnicalExceptionInfoType;
```

Is this a bug? Is it possible to get the same output and stil using "-L" on newer system? In documentation, there is something about typedat file (in fact, a lot about it) but I cannot find an answer to my problem (in fact, this documentation is way to complex to be usable by a casual user).

Comment: I suppose the namespace prefixes may change when running wsdl2h with the WSDL command line arguments in a different order. Just use a typemap.dat file to define `test1="http://system.test.com/datatypes/tehnicalException"` etc. The `-L` option is unlikely to affect this, but the WSDL/XSD order does if the prefixes aren't defined and are therefore assigned in the order that URI are found in the WSDLs.

Comment: This solution has solved my problem.